# double posting when save button is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

a save button sometimes posts one record to the database and other times it repeats that same record twice.
{{ it double posts }} even on a single click. i disabled the button on front end but it doesn't work it still happens.  how can I solve that double post problem . iam using webapi C#  as backend and angular 1 as front end

I tried disabling the button after click.
also tried using the if[!ispostback]{} method still it didn't work out

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Declare a flag variable that will be false initially. Before sending the API request, make the variable true. After successful execution of API, make the flag variable to false. Then in button HTML, just add `[disabled]="flag_variable"`. If you use [FeactiveForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), you can disable the form instance also.

Comment: let me check it out will get back